# react-query as local state manager

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Hi is there any public project/example using react-query exclusively as a local state manager for a react app?

I can only find projects where it's used to fecth data from an API.

Comment: I was wondering the same, will follow.

Comment: Please don't try to do this. It is not what react-query was designed for...

Comment: @TkDodo yes i realize that, but i wanted to see if there's a way (like with SWR) to then explain pros/cons to my team while we evaluate different options

Comment: set staleTime and cacheTime to infinity, set query to enabled: false, pass the data as `initialData`, update with `setQueryData`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like React query works [only with outside data of your app](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/329#discussioncomment-3680):

> React Query is a type of state manager, **specifically designed to
> manage asynchronous state that you get from outside of your app**, so
> server-state, API state, or anything else that is not local client
> state. With that said, it's easy and even encouraged to keep use React
> Query along side a global state manager for your client state.
>
> Its very common for existing applications that after moving their
> server state to React Query, their client state is extremely small and
> doesn't even need an external library like Redux. However, some
> applications actually do have a lot of local client state to manage
> and something like Redux is warranted.
>
> I will link to a talk about this very subject very soon. But you can
> feel good pressing forward using both React Query for anything that is
> asynchronous data and Redux for anything that is local and
> synchronous.

Comment: It doesn't only work with data outside of the app. It's just that's what it's designed for. You COULD technically use it for local state management.